# Tab index with tabControl

Tags: c#, winforms, tabindex

I have a tabControl control with multiple tabs. For each tab, I am adding tab index arranging the controls from top to bottom.

However, when I click tab during the program the order that the program moves from control to control isn't the order I specified.

Does this have something to do with the tabControl?

I am using the "tabIndex" property for each control.

Edit: Sorry I didn't know about this function, here is what it shows:

http://s7.postimage.org/m9burkbx5/Tab_Order.jpg

The red arrow is the flow the tab makes.

Comment: What's the problem in using the View->TabOrder menu item?

Comment: Extraordinary claims require extraordinary evidence.  View + Tab Order and post a screenshot.

Comment: @Hans I think he is using directly the tabIndex property for each control, but he get confused because this property is relative to the container control.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With TabOrder tool active, first click on each container controls (eg. the groupboxes) then, if the controls order inside the groupboxes, is not correct, click on each control in the order you desire them.
You will see the number change accordingly to your clicks. Sometimes happens to click in the wrong order, in this case close the TabOrder tool and reopen to restart again.